# Getting a path through a for loop loses the part after the spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following in a batch file:

```
for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -Q "set nocount on;declare @sql_path varchar(100);exec xp_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\ClientSetup','SQLPath',@sql_path output;select @sql_path AS SQL_Path;"') do set ColumnVar=%%a
echo %ColumnVar%
pause
```

I can see from the echo that ColumnVar is getting set to C:\Program but I have run the sql seperately, and know that it should be getting C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools

How do I set ColumnVar to be the whole of the variable, not just the part before the first space? I have tried putting quotes around the %%a  ie `set ColumnVar="%%a"` but that just gives "C:\Program"!

Comment: A space is a standard delimiter and you are processing the first token (first part until the first space). Set "delims=" to use no delimiters: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ...` to get the whole string.

Comment: Another way might be to use `"tokens=*"` to get everything into %%a.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you that did the trick! It also helped me understand a bit more about bat files.

Comment: better understanding is one of the main points on this site. @Liturgist: correct, but he "tokens" Approach does not get everything `"tokens=*"` eats leading spaces, `delims="` does not. In some cases omitting them may be wanted (like here probably), in other cases (think of parsing a file) omitting leading spaces could ruin formatting). Keep both possibilties in mind.